# The motivation for quivers?

Tags: terminology, math-history, quiver

I would like to know about the reasons (I mean, methodological reasons, not just a penchant for innovation in terminology) for Pierre Gabriel to make use of quivers. Is it fair to say he wanted to account, through such representation, for finite-dimensional associative algebras? Which reasons can you name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question has [an answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/158925) on MathOverflow. It quotes Gabriel: ‘Für einen solchen $4$-Tupel schlagen wir die Bezeichnung *Köcher* vor, und nicht etwa Graph, weil letzerem Wort schon zu viele verwandte Begriffe anhaften.’ (For such a $4$-tuple we suggest the name *quiver*, rather than graph, since too many related concepts are already attached to the latter word.)

Comment: @Brian M. Scott I know he wanted to avoid confusions with the term graph....but what I want to know is what he wanted to used them for? For finite-dimensional associative algebras, o for other kinds of mathematical objects?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/373781/110831) (especially the first paragraph) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks....I will have a look at it.....